# How can I edit the urls.py of allauth?

Tags: python, django

I want to edit the urls.py of allauth by removing the links to the change email and password reset pages. Is there a way I can edit the urls.py in order for these pages to not display and return a 404 when the user tries to access them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can import the views from allauth and create your own urls

```
from allauth.some_app.views import a_view

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^(?P<user>\d+)/(?P<pk>\d+)$', a_view, name='detail')
    ...
]
```

To override simply add the concerned pattern before add the allauth url

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^allauth/password_rest/$', NotFoundView),
    url(r'^allauth/', include('allauth.urls')),
    ...
]
```

Comment: It depends on how you wanna customize those views, you can use inheritance or call them into your view or copy their code and reuse it

Comment: When I'm importing a_view, wouldn't it just be taking the default view from allauth? How would I call that particular url to my view and then copying their code and editing it the way I want?

Comment: Hmm, I see but how do I edit the sign up view for example when a_view is getting the default template from allauth, How do I make my own form to override this page's form?

Comment: in the settings file `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = "my_app.forms.MySignupForm"`

Comment: This will just add extra fields to the default form and not override it. Also, it won't allow me to customize the page in anyway.